# Problem with the out put of the ecc_decryption_key using libtomcrypt in C

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve, libtomcrypt

I Have the following simple code.

Im just initializing the parameters, calling a make_key function, encrypting the data and trying to decrypted the data

```
#define LTM_DESC 
#include <tomcrypt.h>
int main(void)
{
    ecc_key mykey;
    prng_state prng;
    int err, prng_idx , hash_idx;

    ltc_mp = ltm_desc;

    /* register yarrow */
    if (register_prng(&yarrow_desc) == -1) {
    printf("Error registering Yarrow\n");
    return -1;
    }
    
    if (register_hash(&sha1_desc) == -1) {
        printf("Error registering sha1");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    prng_idx = find_prng("yarrow");
    hash_idx = find_hash("sha1");
    /* setup the PRNG */
    if ((err = rng_make_prng(128, find_prng("yarrow"), &prng, NULL))
    != CRYPT_OK) {
    printf("Error setting up PRNG, %s\n", error_to_string(err));
    return -1;
    }
    /* make a 192-bit ECC key */
    if ((err = ecc_make_key(&prng, find_prng("yarrow"), 55, &mykey))
        != CRYPT_OK) {
        printf("Error making key: %s\n", error_to_string(err));
    return -1;
    }

        const unsigned char *plaintext = (const unsigned char *)"Hello, this is a secret message!";
        unsigned long ptlen = sizeof(plaintext);
        unsigned char ciphertext[1024];
        unsigned long ctlen = sizeof(ciphertext);

    if ((err = ecc_encrypt_key(plaintext,                       // const unsinged char *in
                                    ptlen,                             //unsinged long inlen
                                    ciphertext,                       // unsinged *out
                                    &ctlen,                           // unsinged long *outlen
                                    &prng,                               // prng_state *prng
                                    prng_idx,                         // int wprng
                                    hash_idx,                         // int hash
                                    &mykey)) != CRYPT_OK) {           // ecc_key *ley
            printf("Erro ao criptografar o texto: %s\n", error_to_string(err));
            return -1;
}

printf("Text after encrypted: ");
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < ctlen; ++i) {
        printf("%02x", ciphertext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    unsigned char decryptedtext[2048];
    unsigned long decrypted_len = sizeof(decryptedtext);
    if ((err = ecc_decrypt_key(ciphertext, ctlen, decryptedtext, &decrypted_len, &mykey)) != CRYPT_OK) {
        printf("Erro ao descriptografar o texto: %s\n", error_to_string(err));
        return -1;
    }

    decryptedtext[decrypted_len] = '\0';

    printf("%d",decryptedtext == plaintext);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Text after decrypted: %.*s\n", (int)decrypted_len, decryptedtext);
    printf("Text after decrypted: %s\n", plaintext);

    printf("Text after decryptedo: ");
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < decrypted_len; ++i) {
        printf("%c", decryptedtext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    // Update decrypted_len based on the actual length of the decrypted text
decrypted_len = strlen((char *)decryptedtext);

// Print the decrypted text
printf("Text after decrypted: %s\n", decryptedtext);

printf("Text after decrypted (Hex): ");
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < decrypted_len; ++i) {
    printf("%02x", decryptedtext[i]);
}
printf("\n");


return 0;
}
```

in my terminal im compiling using

`gcc -Wall -O0 -g test2.c -ltomcrypt -o test2`

I'd like to see after the line

`printf("Text after decrypted: %s\n", decryptedtext);`

`Text decrypted: Hello, this is a secret message!`

but I'm seeing

`Text decrypted: Hello, t`

Why the print isnt complete?
I dont know what to do to see the complete mensage decrypted.

** NEWS

I got news, apparently, doesnt matter the variable 'decrypted_len' after i call the function ecc_decrypted_key it will be set in 8.

What can I do?

Comment: `sizeof()` returns a `size_t`, not an `unsigned long`.  They are **not** the same, even if `size_t` might be implemented on your system as `unsigned long`.

Comment: Per the LibTomCrypt documentation (notably 12.6 in crypt-1.18.2.pdf, available [here](https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/releases)), `ecc_encrypt_key` is not intended for encrypting long messages directly. It encrypts a short string no longer than the message digest. I presume from your results that is eight bytes. You should refer to the documentation and redesign your program to use other routines.

Comment: Please do not fill your post with repeated or nonsense content as a way to work around the quality filter. If the system prompts you to add additional explanation to your post, then do so. Don't attempt to bypass the warning. This is considered an abuse of the system, and may lead to your post being summarily removed and/or your account being sanctioned.  Take the [tour], read up on [ask] and then [edit] your post with more details.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
const unsigned char *plaintext = (const unsigned char *)"Hello, this is a secret message!";
unsigned long ptlen = sizeof(plaintext);
```

Sets `ptlen` to the size of the *pointer* `plaintext`.

This code will be better

```
const unsigned char plaintext[] = "Hello, this is a secret message!";
unsigned long ptlen = sizeof(plaintext);
```

But that would still be subject to the length limitations of ECC encryption.